# In webpack what is the difference between path and publicPath

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have my webpack config file shown below that bundles `main.js` from `./src/` into `./lib/public`

What exactly is the publicPath doing? I can see that only the `path` specifies the folder the js bundle will go into?

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './lib/public/',
    publicPath: 'public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd like to add to this question: when would you use `path` and when would you use `publicPath`?

Comment: @wmock They are different,  they do not exclude each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use is to define the location of your assets (images etc.). I.e. you can load assets from a custom directory or a CDN even by setting it. See [output.publicPath](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) at the official documentation for further information.

Answer (score 0):

`publicPath` : your public images , css files are saved here

`path` : js build bundle is saved in this file

Answer (score 0):

**Extended explanation**

**path:** Is absolute path where we want to place build files, after doing commands like: `yarn build/npm run build`. In other words, that is physical location on hard disk which we choose to save our files.

Example: `output: {path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'}`. It means we can found our built files on: absolute path /current path in which this line of code is/build/. That is physical location of our built files.

**publicPath:** Is relative path on which your files will be served on server.

Example: `output: {publicPath: '/assets/js/', filename: 'main.js'}`. Your files now on server will be served on path: `/assets/js/main.js`

You can use `webpack-manifest-plugin` which will create `manifest.json` file and when open it, you can see that `publicPath` is added before each value in `mainfest.json` file.

**Short answer:**

**output.publicPath** is value in your `manfiest.json` how you can reference your files.
**output.path** is physical location of built files.

**output.path: 'build/'** all files which you built will be located into `build` folder.

**output.publicPath: 'foo/bar'** all your files will be referenced through `foo/bar` address, which you can in manifest mapped differently.